# Employer doesn't answer and doesn't close the project

Tags: freelance-websites, payments

This was my first job on freelancer site. The project was to add some 'feature' to the C# application. Budget was 10 - 30$. My bid of 20$ was accepted and then it turned out that I was supposed to add 26 forms in 24 hours. I replied  with the message that I won't do this for 20$. Then we agreed on 100$. I wanted to do this job more because of that was my first job there. So I accepted the invitation and changed milestone to 100$.

I was working all day and night long and managed to complete it in time. But there was no income milestones. Just my requested milestone. I sent all files to him and he was happy with it. He also requested some changes and everything was committed on time and client said it was good.

Now he is not answering to my messages. I see him online sometimes and I wrote 10 messages, but he doesn't reply.

What can I do in this scenario? I don't want money. I wanted a good feedback rather than money. But I don't have money nor feedback. I just have a project that was not completed in time, as site states.

And now I want to leave a feedback for that client. But how can I do this? What should I do in this scenario?

Comment: I lurked for a while in odesk/upwork. The rates are impracticable, the customers ask the world for a shitty pay, and on top of that you have to pay 15% commission to the damn site. Only a few jobs are worthwhile. One of the golden rules before accepting jobs is browsing the history of the customer. As a rule I would never accept a job nor from a few countries, neither from who is not able to write a single paragraph accurately. You have to consider you got a lesson that cost you "$100" and keep going on. Very little can be done about it. I would write to their helpdesk/support and move on.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro The commission is 10%. Elance was a wonderful 8.9 but they're dead now... Anyway, you don't have to take the shitty customers, just be judicious when accepting projects.

Comment: The answer you accepted is not correct. Contact the site's support team and tell them you completed the work and the client said it was good. They will try to help you get your money.

Comment: I do agree @user45623, the rates in Elance were impracticable, once in a blue moon, there were some interest project...UpWorks seems a joke or oriented to the 3rd world market.

Comment: Upwork is getting better now that Elance is closed and the serious clients have been forced over to Upwork. Not everyone is looking for 3rd-world developers.

Comment: If they are not looking for 3rd-word specialists they are masking it very well...it is enough to look at the going rates, they are ridiculous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid that you were conned. You will neither get your money or your feedback. To post the feedback, the clients needs to pay you at least some money.

In the future, don't do any work without a milestone being LOADED. Your request means nothing. Loaded milestone means that the money is on the freelancer site (in escrow) and that you can safely do your work.

Try contacting client that you will work for $10 and great feedback. However, since you send him files, I am afraid that you will not get even those $10.

PS. report the client to the customer service. He should be flagged and possibly banned. I think odesk has made great efforts to ban both bad contractors and clients.

Comment: Yee, that is completely my fault. That was my first project. I have already contacted support team and they said the same. They should ban such people from the site. Well, at least I have one lesson learned.

Comment: Excellent recommendation about the milestone being loaded! The fact is despite being banned they will come back with another account. They actually might have been only the middlemen for a better paying customer.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro They cannot do it zillion of times. Each time they ban you, they ban the credit card you used, I think. So they can do it a few times OR they can catch new guys because new guys will never see odesk title like "credit card not verified". That's why my suggestion on loading the milestone will help as to load the money, they will have to attach a valid card.

Comment: Be sure to look at history. Back here in Portugal I never give my real CC in the Internet. *Ever. I create a virtual CC for *every* single transaction. I can define a maximum limit,  and wether they work a single time for paying for something, or wether they work for a fixed amount of time, say for Apple Store, for a developer account or for a magazine subscription. They cannot be (re)used for other purposes.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I was not aware something like that is possible. I guess it's the same as the gift card but more advanced :).

Comment: Very handy for dealing with vendors in aliexpress.

Comment: Bad answer. The site may be able to help him get the money back. I've used that route before. It doesn't always work, but it's clear the asker here hasn't tried and doesn't realize that's an option. You shouldn't be telling him to give up when he hasn't explored all his options.

Comment: @user45623 If the client has not loaded any money in the milestone, no site can force him to load the money. They can ban his account, but a conman will simply open a new account with a new card. So saying again, he will not get either his money or feedback unless Jesus tells this guy to do the proper thing.

Comment: Peter is correct. I have contacted support team but they said that they can only send email to the client. So I was just cheated because of lack of experience on the site.

Comment: As one guy pointed here, in many countries you can open virtual credit card. so if they ban your account and card, you can open a new one. something that these conmen are aware of

Answer (score 0):

Ask the website for assistance. They can often assist you in getting your money if you prove that you did the work and that the client was satisfied. They have a vested interest in you getting paid, because if you don't get paid then neither do they. Just contact their support team.

Comment: They can help if there was milestone from client. If not than I can not dispute it.